# python tkinter using variables across files,?

Tags: python-2.7

I have been playing with Tkinter in Python 2.7, and just ran across something that SHOULD be a bug, but isn't and the program seems to work OK still.

To make my program more manageable, I have split it into separate .py files.

One file (called globs.py) is a list of global variables in the form

```
global var_1
global var_2
...
```

Then I import globs into my other files.

In another file I can set the variable, thus...

```
import globs
globs.var_1 = "some value"
```

In a third file I can use it..

```
import globs
if globs.var_1 == "something":
...
```

So far, all is as expected, but...

I just found out if the variable is NOT mentioned in the globs.py file at all, the program still seems to work OK.

Is this intended behavior? Any other programming language would give a 'variable not found' error.

If it is intended, why should I even setup any variables in globs.py?

What are the drawbacks?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: If you have a line of code that says `x = 4` and the next line says `x = 5`, then `x` will be 5.  If you take out the first line, the result will be the same.  What is happening here is very similar.

Comment: this question has absolutely nothing to do with tkinter.